# How to add dynamic sort by direction to NHibernate queryover

Tags: c#, linq, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to add dynamic order by direction to my nhibernate queryover. Can anyone help how to do this? I was able to add dynamic orderby field. but dont know how to do the order by direction. Please find below my code:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField))
    {
        var sortByProperty = Helper.GetSortByProperty(sortField);
        if (sortByProperty != null)
        {
            query.OrderBy(x => sortByProperty.GetValue(x, null));
        }
    }

    var result = query.Skip(pageIndex*pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .Future<Member>();
```

Comment: Can you show full code for the final solution? Including the implementation of Helper.GetSortByProperty & sortByProperty.GetValue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I have done this is, passing in a [`ListSortDirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) type variable to the function that is doing the query.

So then you could apply the

- `OrderBy()` which:

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.

- `OrderByDescending()` which:

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order according to a key.

on your `IQueryable<T>` depending on the values from `ListSortDirection.Ascending` or `ListSortDirection.Descending`.

---

As requested by OP in comments, added sample generic code:

```
public IList<T> GetEntityList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpression, ListSortDirection orderDirection, int totalPages, int start, int limit)
{
    IList<T> returnVar;
    using (var session = _nhibernate.OpenSession())
    {
        var firstQueryable = session.Query<T>().Where(whereExpression);

        IQueryable<T> secondQueryable = orderDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? firstQueryable.OrderBy(orderByExpression) : firstQueryable.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression);

        returnVar = totalPages > 0 ? secondQueryable.Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList() : secondQueryable.ToList();    
    }

    return returnVar;
}
```

---

To address another question in comment from OP, for the `QueryOver` API, for instance you can use the `.OrderBy(orderByExpression).Desc` for reverse sorting.

Comment: Ok. Would you mind share the sample code for orderby with custom property and custom direction please?

Comment: thanks. is this same for QueryOver? Sorry i am not very much experienced wth NHibernate